# Redux-Saga connect multiple generators to store

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

This may be fairly basic but I haven't found an solution.  I'm using [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) to handle my async API calls with redux.  I need to connect multiple listeners to the store.  I tried `fork` like in the examples, and the first fork works, but the second one doesn't.  How can I connect multiple listeners?

```
export default function* mySaga() {
  yield [
    fork(yield* takeEvery("FRIEND_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchFriends)), // works
    fork(yield* takeEvery("CREATE_USER_REQUESTED", createUser)),    // doesn't work
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got same problem, I found another way

```
export default function* root(){
    yield [
        takeEvery("FRIEND_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchFriends),
        takeEvery("CREATE_USER_REQUESTED", createUser)
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `fork` takes a **function that returns a promise** or a **generator function** as per the documentation here:

http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#forkfn-args

To make your situation work, just put the `yield*` in a generator function and it should all work :

```
export default function* mySaga() {
  yield [
    fork(watchFetchFriends),
    fork(watchCreateUser)
  ]
}
function watchFetchFriends() {
   yield* takeEvery("FRIEND_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchFriends);
}
function watchCreateUser() {
    yield* takeEvery("CREATE_USER_REQUESTED", createUser);
}
```

Btw, I am not sure how your first `yield*` works though.

Comment: The generator first evaluates the yield* by spreading it and waiting for the delegate generator takeEvery to return. That's why the first yield* works

Comment: @YassineElouafi Perhaps we could throw an exception if we detect that a `yield*` is passed to `fork` ?

Comment: thanks so much @ganaraj this solves it!  Also helps if you include `import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects'` XD

Comment: @ganaraj that's impossible, `yield*` is handled at the runtime level. All userland code sees is a flattened iterator

Comment: @YassineElouafi Created doc issue https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/323

Answer (score 0):

Redux Saga uses the `all` function in the recent version (0.15.3) to combine multiple sagas to one root saga for the Redux store.

```
import { takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

...

function *watchAll() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery("FRIEND_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchFriends),
    takeEvery("CREATE_USER_REQUESTED", createUser)
  ]);
}
```